# How can i check if a MySQL SELECT String only exist SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, select

i have a Module where User can create Reports with MySQL Statements. They only have to use SELECT Statements. I check it with `strpos("", $sSelect)`. Is there any Solution, how i can check the String on all other dangerous Statements (like `DROP, Replace, DELETE, TRUNCATE, ALTER,... etc.`). Only SELECT is allowed.

Greetz

Comment: I think  only searching the position of `select` is not a good idea...

Comment: @JordanRichards MySQL is definitely NOT deprecated. The PHP mysql_* API is being deprecated, though but the OP does not mention using it.

Comment: @markus-tharkun oh yes, sorry. I keep making that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible for you to alter the MySQL user permissions for those people creating the reports?  If so, you could just restrict access to everything bar SELECT?  You would just need to connect as this user type when creating the reports and connect to your normal user account for everything else.

Comment: This is definitely a MUST plus you also NEED to make sure this database user can only access a certain table!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex.

```
if (!preg_match('#^SELECT .*#i', ltrim($your_string))) {
    // not allowed...
}
```

if the string doesn't start with the SELECT statement (case insensitive) do something...

However, this isn't the best way, you must consider to limit user permissions!
In addition with this approach a "bad guy" could execute another command in this way: `SELECT ...; DROP TABLE ...;`

Comment: The problem is that you're answering the wrong question. This MUST not be solved by trying to parse the query, which will never be good enough, this has to be controlled with appropriate mysql users and permissions.

Comment: That's for sure... but even if that was a wrong question I don't mine it's a wrong answer: it works! maybe it isn't the best way, but it works! anyway... no problem! :)

Comment: A good answer points out that it is the wrong question, it doesn't give the right answer to a bad question.